# How to fix Http request failure when trying to query the Microsoft Dataverse Web API from Power Automate?

Tags: httprequest, odata, power-automate, fetchxml, dataverse

I'm trying to retrieve all the users and their roles across some environments in my Office 365 tenant using a Power Automate flow, but when I'm trying to query the Dataverse Web API either with OData or fetchXml, I always get the same error:

[image]

[image]

At this point I don't have any clue on how to fix it, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I also tried this in postman and it works without problem.

Thanks for your help.

I'm adding some extra information below.

**URI**

https://someorg.crm2.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/systemusers

**Headers**

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
  "OData-Version": "4.0",
  "Prefer": "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"",
  "If-None-Match": "null",
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
```

**Query**

```
<fetch top="1000">
  <entity name="systemuser">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="domainname" />
    <link-entity name="systemuserroles" from="systemuserid" to="systemuserid" intersect="true">
      <link-entity name="role" from="roleid" to="roleid" intersect="true">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="roleid" />
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: How are u encoding the URI? I can't access this API right now but have you saw the doc? Your query doesn't seem the correct format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/use-fetchxml-web-api

Comment: @ojonasplima Hey. Yes, I'm encoding the fetchXml query using this tool https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

I just provided it in that way here so it's more readable.

Comment: the fact that works in Postman means something is wrong inside Power Automate. Did you try also the OData query inside Postman and works?

Comment: Setting the content type to JSON and providing XML, are you sure Postman has that header?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Haven't tried OData inside Postman yet, just fetchXml.

Comment: @Skin Yes, just re-checked and it has the header, I don't know what could be wrong. Tried removing the content type header in Power Automate and got the same error.

Comment: You can use an encodeuriComponent function to encode your fetchXml in Power Automate. I have shared an example setup in this thread: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Action-HTTP-failed-while-trying-to-query-the-Dataverse-API/m-p/1867550/highlight/true#M108466